# Interpreting a Futures Quote

Tags: india, stock-markets, futures

I am trying to understand an F&O Quote page.

http://www.moneycontrol.com/india/fnoquote/infosys/IT/2014-06-26

Spot Price 2993.15

Volume 778732

This means 778732 shares were traded on the last trading day.

Futures Price 3004.70

No. of Contracts Traded 14,210

Turnover (Rs. in lakhs) 53,316.28

Open Interest 3,798,750

Volume 1,776,250

What do the numbers for Futures mean ?

I know what a futures contract is .. but where do I find out the exact meaning of the above numbers ?

Please assist.

Comment: http://www.investopedia.com/

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ At first I was going to flag your comment for being unconstructive, but then I saw that it answered the question rather well. :)

Comment: @dg99, thank you. It was the simplest response to give the resources needed without getting into whether this is a personal finance and money question and so on. It seemed a reasonable compromise :) I actually put thought in my responses, sometimes they just end up requiring very few words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spot Price - The price of the market for immediate delivery usually 2 days clearing. As opposed to the market for delivery at expiration (usually a few months away)

Futures Price - the price of the Futures contract, as opposed to the spot price above.

Volume - This is the number of contracts traded * the contract price. The actual money that changed hands.

No. of Contracts Traded : Number of contracts written in the day.

Turnover (Rs. in lakhs): The number contracts that were written and scratched for the day.

Open Interest : The monetary value of all the contracts written and currently open for this expiration.